# how to keep materials when use realize instances - Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I created the geometry node according to the images below, the object I'm using in the node is this "lamp" with random color between red and white. But when I use the *Realize Geometry* node all the colors change only to red.

That is, I would like to know how to keep materials without geometry nodes using perform geometry.

[image]this is without realize

[image]this is with realize

[image]this is the shade that I'm using

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Could you please explain this in more detail or share your blend file with us? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=akOjrdmL" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/akOjrdmL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example in Blender 3.2

Geo node setup

[image]

Shader setup

[image]

We basically create a random value in geo nodes and pass it to the shader editor via a custom attribute ( called _id in this example), per instance. We set the material in the geo nodes and read it as a factor of the colorramp node ( set on constant).

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but unfortunately it didn't work for me...

This is my file.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=akOjrdmL" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/akOjrdmL/)

Comment: Ignore, I didn't know I had to bind the attribute in the output...

thanks for this... it worked perfectly!

Comment: Battled with this forever and it is so simple :D - Thank you so much!